# "GET /assets/)!==t&&(e.html(e.data( HTTP/1.1" 200 3538 "-" "Java/1.7.0_25"

Tags: httpd, log-files, hacking

I'm seeing GET requests like:

```
"GET /assets/)!==t&&(e.html(e.data( HTTP/1.1" 200 3538 "-" "Java/1.7.0_25"
```

in my logs for a box hosting a Rails app. Looks suspiciously like someone probing the app but can't be sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly a bot probing for exploits. That code looks to be part of a few generic Javascript unpackers. My guess is that they're looking for an XSS exploit that they can pile packed JS into for whatever purpose.

Check to make sure the exploits don't work (because you're safely escaping all user supplied content displayed on the page) and you can safely ignore them.